# How to send https reuqest using pysocks python

Tags: python, python-3.x

***every thing working fine only how to send https request using Pysocks ?***

```
import socks

s = socks.socksocket()

s.set_proxy(socks.HTTP, "proxy", port)

s.connect(("example.com", 443))
request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nSec-Fetch-Site: none\r\nSec-Fetch-Mode: navigate\r\nSec-Fetch-Dest: document\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r\n\r\n"
s.sendall(request.encode())
result = s.recv(4096)
while (len(result) > 0):
     print(str(result))
     result = s.recv(1024)
     result
```

***Response***

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: exit code `0` usually means that all is OK.

Comment: create code with real URL so we could simply copy and test it. OR maybe problem makes only this URL ? OR maybe problem is proxy ? Did you test it with different settings/urls?

Comment: to send `HTTPS` you may need module `SSL` or `SSLSocket`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect with secure `HTTPS` you need [ssl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) as wrapper on your original socket.

```
import socks
import ssl

s = socks.socksocket()

#s.set_proxy(socks.HTTP, "proxy", port)  # I don't have proxy server

s.connect(("httpbin.org", 443))
ss = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile=None, certfile=None, server_side=False, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

request = "GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nSec-Fetch-Site: none\r\nSec-Fetch-Mode: navigate\r\nSec-Fetch-Dest: document\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r\n\r\n"
ss.sendall(request.encode())

result = ss.recv(4096)
while result:
     print(result.decode())
     result = ss.recv(1024)
```

I tested it with real url https://httpbin.org/get which sends back all data send to server.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 18 Dec 2020 02:23:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 733
Connection: close
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true


{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7", 
    "Host": "example.com", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5fdc129f-055e9976503fef011cc031c0"
  }, 
  "origin": "217.99.86.56", 
  "url": "https://example.com/get"
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

It works for me also with local [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) proxy server

```
s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9050)  # TOR proxy server
```